# Ehcache jgroup replication issue [FIND_INITIAL_MBRS FIND_MBRS ] are required by GMS, but not provided

Tags: kubernetes, ehcache, jgroups

Our project moved from tradition tomcat deployment to kubernetes just now. Previously, Ehache replication was working using RMI Replicator. RMI relication is also now not working with Kubernetes so I am trying to replicate ehcache kubernetes using jroups. Without using kubernetes everything is working but during deployment I am getting below log.

I ma using K3s and application is in springboot.

I have followed this tutorial
https://github.com/kunal-bhatia/ehcache-jgroups-demo

```
ERROR n.s.e.d.j.JGroupsCacheManagerPeerProvider:140 - Failed to create JGroups Channel, replication will not function. JGroups properties:
null
java.lang.Exception: events [FIND_INITIAL_MBRS FIND_MBRS ] are required by GMS, but not provided by any of the protocols below it
at org.jgroups.stack.Configurator.sanityCheck(Configurator.java:503)
at org.jgroups.stack.Configurator.connectProtocols(Configurator.java:223)
at org.jgroups.stack.Configurator.setupProtocolStack(Configurator.java:123)
at org.jgroups.stack.Configurator.setupProtocolStack(Configurator.java:57)
at org.jgroups.stack.ProtocolStack.setup(ProtocolStack.java:476)
at org.jgroups.JChannel.init(JChannel.java:852)
```

tcp.xml file

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="urn:org:jgroups"
        xsi:schemaLocation="urn:org:jgroups http://www.jgroups.org/schema/jgroups.xsd">
    <TCP
            bind_addr="match-interface:eth0,match-interface:lo"
            bind_port="7810"
            recv_buf_size="5M"
            send_buf_size="1M"
            max_bundle_size="64K"
            enable_diagnostics="true"
            thread_naming_pattern="cl"

            thread_pool.min_threads="0"
            thread_pool.max_threads="500"
            thread_pool.keep_alive_time="30000"/>

    <org.jgroups.protocols.kubernetes.KUBE_PING
            namespace="${KUBE_NAMESPACE:ehcache-demo}"/>

    <MERGE3 max_interval="30000"
            min_interval="10000"/>

    <VERIFY_SUSPECT timeout="1500"/>

    <BARRIER/>
    <pbcast.NAKACK2 xmit_interval="500"
                    xmit_table_num_rows="100"
                    xmit_table_msgs_per_row="2000"
                    xmit_table_max_compaction_time="30000"
                    use_mcast_xmit="false"
                    discard_delivered_msgs="true"/>
    <UNICAST3
            xmit_table_num_rows="100"
            xmit_table_msgs_per_row="1000"
            xmit_table_max_compaction_time="30000"/>
    <pbcast.STABLE stability_delay="1000" desired_avg_gossip="50000"
                   max_bytes="8m"/>
    <pbcast.GMS print_local_addr="true" join_timeout="3000"
                view_bundling="true"/>
    <MFC max_credits="2M"
         min_threshold="0.4"/>
    <FRAG2 frag_size="60K"/>
    <pbcast.STATE_TRANSFER/>
    <CENTRAL_LOCK/>
    <COUNTER/>
</config>
```